# How to Determine that Talkback has Finished Announcing Something

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I am working on adding accessibility I am attempting to have a toast be read after another element is focused on. The previous element is getting cut off before finishing.

Attempting to focus & delay on the toast itself did work somewhat but now there is an unintended announcement prompting me to open the talkback menu. I am not an ios dev but I know that there is `announcementDidFinishNotification` for ios. Is there an equivalent for this on Android?

Comment: This question was interesting for me too,but there is no way to do this. Yes,from api 26 you can probably catch audioFocus of accessibility stream,but there is no guaranty,what it will be screenreader in this stream.